# store credits not deducting from total from checkout

Tags: opencart

currently in my opencart (1.5.6) i have enabled to use store credits. At the checkout

I have added $1000 worth of credits and when i purchase a product worth $1800 but in the checkout it shows

```
Store Credit:    USD. -18.00
```

usually it reduces only 1% from the available credits.

i need to deduct all the available credits from the cart value. I went through the store credits files and couldn't find a place where its calculated.

Can someone please tell me how can i use the total credits.

Comment: is this `store credit` thing comes built in opencart or you installed some extension ?

Comment: @ChetanPaliwal its the builtin extension. I just added only an extension to show the available credits. I did try disabling that extension but its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the backend:
Extension -> Order Total -> Store Credit

then the credit will be used automaticaaly!

but point is:

I found it does not work for backedn.
If I place order in the backend, then the order totoal will include store conclude, but the credit in customer does not change!

link:

[Issue on store credit of opencart 1.5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574510/issue-on-store-credit-of-opencart-1-5-6)

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=133015