# Issue on store credit of opencart 1.5.6

Tags: php, opencart

I want to create an order for a customer in the administration. The customer has certain credit (let's say $200). The order total is calculated like `order total - customer's credit = new order total`.

The problem is the customer's credit does not change after creating an order.

For example:

- the order total is: `$500`
- credit is: `$200`
- then the order total is : $500 - $200 = `$300`
- but the customer's credit is still: `$200`

Has anybody else had the same problem?

---

I try to change the status of that order, both processing and setting, but it doesn't work.

The transaction in customer info page does not change.

I have checked the code in backend - there is no code that would operate with `oc_customer_transaction` table.

---

In frontend, there is a function in `/catalog/model/total/credit.php`

```php
public function confirm($order_info, $order_total) {
    $this->language->load('total/credit');
    if ($order_info['customer_id']) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_transaction SET 
                   customer_id = '" . (int)$order_info['customer_id'] . "', 
                   order_id = '" . (int)$order_info['order_id'] . "', 
                   description = '" . $this->db->escape(
                         sprintf($this->language->get('text_order_id'),  
                         (int)$order_info['order_id'])) . "', 
                   amount = '" . (float)$order_total['value'] . "', 
                   date_added = NOW()");

    }
}
```

it is called during the checkout process to recalculate customer's credit balance. But I haven't found such code in backend.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I am sure you could use some little help and explanation how is it going on here, therefor it would be good if you'd find few minutes to read the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) or also take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first. Small hint to your current question(s): your post contains three different questions which makes it *too broad* and probably will be closed. You should split those problems into separate questions (and also do that in the future).

Answer (score 0):

I already fix that.

code:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_transaction SET 
    customer_id = '" . (int)$order_info['customer_id'] . "', 
    order_id = '" . (int)$order_info['order_id'] . "', 
    description = '" . $this->db->escape(
      sprintf($this->language->get('text_order_id'),  
      (int)$order_info['order_id'])) . "', 
    amount = '" . (float)$order_total['value'] . "', 
    date_added = NOW()");
```

just add the credit calculate code when at following place:

1./admin/model/sale/order.php   addOrder method

a. when you add product to a new customer order in the backend, the system will send request to the frontend (/catalog/checkout/mannual.php   index ) wo calculate the order total(such as: subtotal, credit, shipping, total). after this request, order total in the page will be refreshed

b. when you save the order, the (admin/model/sale/order.php) addOrder method will be called eventually. You just need add code above to that function.

```
insert into.....  customer_transaction  means use the credit
```

2./admin/model/sale/order.php   editOrder method

a. when you edit a order, the each item in totals will be changed. so, you should delete all credit you used for this order before.

delete * from oc_customer_transaction where 'order_id'=$order_id

b. since the each item of totals(involve credit) has been recalculated in step1, so this method will receive the new credit amount. just insert the new amount by code blow

3.you do not need to change admin/model/sale/order.php   deleteOrder method
     because it delete all totals, include item in the data table oc_customer_transaction

things done!